# Add javascript in custom widget

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom, widget

I've created a custom widget with a popup on homepage loading, now i need a function to close the popup but i'm not able to include a javascript file in the widget. I've tried the solution that i read in other post but i haven't find the solution yet.

Magento version: 2.1.7

Hope someone can help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: when you say a 'custom widget' do you mean that you created a widget type other then the default ones that you select in the dropdown when you make a new widget? In most cases the widget is pulling in a static block that you can include your js in, are you doing something else here?

Comment: I've created another widget type, i'm using it only for the popup

Comment: could you include the code you used to create it?

Answer (score 5):

Create requirejs-config

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            yourWidgetName: 'NameSpace_ModuleName/js/yourwidgetfile',  
        }
    },
};
```

Define you widget following convention

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($) {
    "use strict";

    $.widget('namespace.yourWidgetName', {
      // Logicial code

      // Optional 
      options: {
         // Define variables
      },

      _create: function() {
         // Init code
         this.closeModal();
      },

      closeModal: function() {
         // Do close modal here
      },


    });

    return $.namespace.yourWidgetName;
});
```

For use widget you can call it anywhere if it defined. Such as in template

```
<div data-mage-init='{"yourWidgetName": {}}' class="container-wrapper" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem using the following script:

```
<script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            title: 'Iscriviti al nostro sito',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

        $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
    }
);
```

Anyway thank you for the help, i hope this can be useful for other users